# Fastest time to Sun Earth L2 (or L1)?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, lagrangian-points, record

Of all the past, present or planned probes to SE-L2 (or L1*) which has or will take the shortest amount of time to arrive from leaving low earth orbit, or from passing that location if the probe doesn't enter LEO before heading to L2 (*or L1 it the travel time is similar)?

Arrival at the general location of L2 is sufficient, I'm not concerned about the length of time it takes to enter a Lissajous orbit.

Comment: I didn't know if an orbit closer to the sun would have different requirements, which would lead to different travel times.

Comment: L2 is more "energetic" in terms of Jacobi constant than L1

Comment: @uhoh To you downvote observation, I'll add a bonus tomorrow, if that might make it worth someone's time. If someone wants to point to the way to do the leg work myself I'm all for it, that is if I'm up for the challenge.  My physics education ended as I was getting ready for the Classical Mechanics class at my university, decades ago.

Comment: @Julio That's with respect to a heliocentric orbit, but starting from LEO (as specified in the question) wouldn't getting to L1 vs L2 require nearly the same delta-v?

Comment: It could be @uhoh, I do not know what happens because CRTBP non-linearities can come into play. I just wanted to remark that L1 and L2 are not the same in terms of energy.

Comment: I wonder if a community wiki might be the way to go here. The lack of answers suggests no-one knows *the* fastest time for sure. But a community wiki would allow someone to post the probe/space telescope/satellite/whatever that took the shortest time they know. Then someone can amend that with one they know took less time, and we might get a good approximate answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best bet for answering this question will be a community wiki, in which we post what we know for several different L1/L2 orbiters. I'll start.

**L1 - the fastest I know:**

- LISA Pathfinder was launched on the [3rd of December 2015](https://sci.esa.int/web/lisa-pathfinder/-/57247-lisa-pathfinder-arrives-at-its-worksite) and reached L1 orbit on the [22nd of January 2016](https://sci.esa.int/web/lisa-pathfinder/-/57247-lisa-pathfinder-arrives-at-its-worksite). So that's 50 days.

**L1 - other:**

- [SOHO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_and_Heliospheric_Observatory) (Solar and Heliospheric Observatory) was launched on December 2nd, 1995 (source: https://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/about/about.html). It arrived in orbit on the 14th of February (source: https://www.esa.int/esapub/bulletin/bullet86/huber86.htm). So that's 74 days to reach L1.
- [ISEE-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Cometary_Explorer) was [launched on August the 12th 1978 and reached L1 on the 20th of November](https://web.archive.org/web/20150610112432/http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/profile.cfm?MCode=ISEEICE). That's 100 days.
- [Genesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_(spacecraft)) was launched on August the 8th 2001 and entered L1 orbit [on the 16th of November](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/genesis/in-depth/) - so 100 days.
- [DSCOVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Climate_Observatory) was launched February 11 2015, and reached L1 on the 8th of June - so 117 days.

**L2 - the fastest I know:**

- [Gaia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_(spacecraft)) was launched on the 19th of December 2013 and reached L2 orbit on [January 8th 2014](http://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Gaia/Gaia_enters_its_operational_orbit) - so a mere 20 days! In fact, the report of its entering L2 orbit may have been published a few hours after this happened, so it *may* be as little as 19 days and X hours!

**L2 - other missions:**

- According to the [European Space Agency](https://archive.ph/1v7w), [Planck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_(spacecraft)) was launched on the 14th of May 2009 and reached L2 orbit on the 3rd of July. So that's 50 days.
- [Herschel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herschel_Space_Observatory#Launch_and_orbit) was launched on May 14th 2009, along with Planck. According to Wikipedia, it reached L2 "approximately sixty days after launch". Still, [its observation mission didn't get started until the autumn](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/herschel/latest-news).
- [Chang'e 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_2) reached the L2 point by a rather different route - it had an earlier mission which required it to be orbiting the Moon. When that was complete, it left that orbit on June 8th 2011 and arrived on August 25th - 78 days. So that's slower and it's a route starting at high instead of low Earth orbit, but I thought it might interest the OP anyway.
- [Spektr-RG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spektr-RG) 
  apparently took [100 days](https://spaceflightnow.com/2019/10/23/german-x-ray-telescope-achieves-first-light/) to reach L2.

**L2 - planned missions:**

- The [James Webb Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope#Mission), according to [NASA](https://jwst.nasa.gov/content/about/faqs/faq.html#threemonths), is expected to launch in March of 2021 and to take ["about a month to travel this distance"](https://jwst.nasa.gov/content/about/faqs/faq.html#threemonths). However, it won't be ready to start its mission until [several more months](https://jwst.nasa.gov/content/about/orbit.html) of tests and preparation after reaching L2.
- [Euclid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_(spacecraft)) is expected to launch some time in [mid 2022](http://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Arianespace_and_ESA_announce_the_Euclid_satellite_s_launch_contract_for_dark_energy_exploration) and to take [approximately 30 days](https://sci.esa.int/web/euclid/-/46661-mission-operations) to reach L2.
- There's almost no information on [LiteBIRD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiteBIRD) or [Spektr-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spektr-M).
- [PLATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_Transits_and_Oscillations_of_stars) is planned to [launch in 2025](https://sci.esa.int/documents/33240/36096/1567260308850-PLATO_Definition_Study_Report_1_2.pdf). If I understand [this document](https://sci.esa.int/documents/33240/36096/1567260308850-PLATO_Definition_Study_Report_1_2.pdf) correctly it's intended to leave its "low earth orbit profile" about 2 days after launch, then take another 30 days to reach L2.
- [SPICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICA_(spacecraft)) is expected to launch [some time in 2025 at the earliest](http://cor.gsfc.nasa.gov/copag/aas_jan2015/SPICA_COPAG_4Jan2015.pdf). I don't have any more information.
- [WFIRST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Field_Infrared_Survey_Telescope) is probably too early in the planning stage for anyone to be sure, and it's also faced with cancellation. I think the planned launch date may have been pushed back a few times. Anyway, I couldn't find an estimated time-to-orbit.
- [ARIEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARIEL) is planned to launch in [2028, or maybe 2026](https://web.archive.org/web/20180322105041/https://www.stfc.ac.uk/news/uk-part-of-ariel-exoplanet-project/). I can't find any information on how long it's expected to take to reach L2 orbit.
- [ATHENA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Telescope_for_High_Energy_Astrophysics) is planned to launch [in 2031](https://sci.esa.int/web/athena/-/59896-mission-summary), but that was all the information I could find. It's probably too early to make any estimates for travel time or precise launch date.
- Whichever of the two [LUVOIR probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Technology_Large-Aperture_Space_Telescope) (formerly ATLAST and HDST) is eventually developed, it's intended to have a [mid-2030s launch date](https://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/luvoir/design/). When LUVOIR-B was still ATLAST, it was intended to use ["the JWST orbit and transfer trajectory because it has been well studied and does not require an insertion maneuver"](https://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/ATLAST/tech/Stahl_SPIE_2015_paper.pdf). I do not know if this has changed since 2015.

**L2 - cancelled missions:**

- I can't find any information on when [Eddington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington_mission) was expected to launch, or how long it might have taken to reach L2.
- The [Terrestrial Planet Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Planet_Finder) was expected to take [109 days](https://exep.jpl.nasa.gov/files/exep/STDT_Report_Final_Ex2FF86A.pdf) to reach L2 orbit.

**Craft that I don't have the full information for:**

- [WIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WIND_(spacecraft)) was launched on the [1st of November 1994](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/v-w-x-y-z/wind) into *"a double-lunar-swingby orbit near the ecliptic plane with an apogee from 80 to 250 RE and a perigee of 5 to 10 RE"*. It was inserted into halo orbit around L1 some time in November 1996, after making several observations in its previous orbit. If "RE" means "Earth Radiuses", this was a high-Earth orbit that may have been designed to eventually bring it close to L1. It looks like it exited its "halo" orbit and entered "petal" orbits in June 1996, in preparation for exiting L1 orbit. It moved to L2, and I [don't](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/v-w-x-y-z/wind) [think](https://www-spof.gsfc.nasa.gov/istp/news/9804/) it got close enough to Earth to be in LEO, whether or not it resumed an Earth-centric orbit. It returned to L1 in [early 2004](https://wind.nasa.gov/).

  I do not believe that it broke the record for LEO - Lagrange travel time, but the information sources I have examined were incomplete and I could only work out a partial picture.
- [WMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_Microwave_Anisotropy_Probe#cite_note-2003Bennett-18) was launched on the 30th of June, 2001. Sources claim that it took about [three months](https://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/news/facts.html) to reach L2. I'd put that down as roughly 90 days - *except* that [one NASA page](https://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/news/events.html) quotes the three month figure but also gives a date of August 10 2001 - which would be less than two months. [The press release announcing its arrival at L2](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2001/10/011003065222.htm) is dated October 3 2001, so this would give us a travel time of 95 days. However, [a published research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0302207) states *"By 10 August 2001, WMAP was sufficiently stable in its L2 orbit for CMB data taking to commence."* So we either have 41 days or 95 days, and disagreement as to exactly what counted as a stable L2 orbit may be the reason.

Anyone who can beat these records, I've made this a community wiki, so please edit them in!

Comment: `+1` for initiative! The problem with using "wikiblurbs" for comparison is that they can be wrong, or not directly comparable. For example, if a spacecraft approaches a halo orbit along a stable manifold trajectory, there is no well-defined point where you can say definitively that it's reached orbit. For those trajectories that have well-defined insertion burns, then we can note those. Anyway, let's see how it goes...

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for that. I admit that I don't understand orbital mechanics well enough to follow your point, but I do certainly understand that there is potential inaccuracy in the figures. They're all I've got to go by, but maybe someone with information allowing for more accurate and comparable times-to-orbit will edit this answer.

Comment: Okay the wiki really helps! I can have a look to see how much can be deduced from the data in [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi)

Comment: WIND could be a tricky one to research (https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/v-w-x-y-z/wind) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WIND_(spacecraft))  - it's moved between Earth-centric orbit, L1 orbit, L2 orbit, L1 again and I don't yet have the full information on how long any of these traversals took or whether it temporarily entered into Earth orbit on the way.

Comment: @uhoh It looks like WMAP was an example of the problem you describe. At the very least, I've got contradictory dates as to when it reached L2 orbit.

Comment: OK, I've worked through everything at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_objects_at_Lagrangian_points and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point#Lagrangian_spacecraft_and_missions . I don't know of any other missions, so I won't be adding any more. However, for the LUVOIR probes, I haven't read the documents at https://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/luvoir/reports/ . This is because I'm not sure my laptop could handle rendering a 125MB PDF! Could someone with a powerful PC have a look at those?

Comment: As a TLDR because this answer is now quite long - the fastest times I have are 20 days for L2 (Gaia) and 50 days for L1 (LISA Pathfinder).

Comment: _Wind_ used the moon to get to L2 and L1, so I don't think it was particularly fast.  If you look at Figure 1 in https://www.essoar.org/doi/10.1002/essoar.10504309.2 you will see in the lower left-hand panel the orange path spans ~3 months.  The orbital info on _Wind_ can be found at https://spdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/data_orbits.html.